# Linux software to detect external drive partition-level rootkits

Tags: linux, security, malware, forensics

`clamscan` can search *file systems* for malware, but it can't scan possible rootkits on the boot sectors of an external disk.  `rkhunter` also doesn't seem to provide the ability to scan boot sectors of an external drive.  Is there Linux software which works like:

```
rootkitscanproggie /dev/sdb
```

Where `/dev/sdb` is a just plugged in thumb drive or hard disk?

Desired features:

- Command line interface preferred.
- GPL license
- Searches partition level, *i.e.* an evil boot sector, a malware version of *GRUB*, *etc*.  (Searching file systems is optional, since `clamav` already does that).

---

Note: This isn't a *sanitizing* question -- an external drive can always be wiped using `dd` and such.  This is a **forensics** question, the goals being detection and identification.